# Javascript startsWith not working on iPhone and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, safari

I'm getting the following error ONLY on mobile Safari and IE.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The offending code is:

```
if(window.location.origin.startsWith(shopAddress + "/account/login")  && 
sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn') == "true")
```

This works beautifully in Chrome and Firefox. Any idea why Safari & IE don't like it?

Comment: Both browsers do not support `String.prototype.startsWith`, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

Comment: well sh*t.. yea its the `startsWith` that's the issue..

Comment: Ahh I added the Polyfill method defined in that link and its working well now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add following polyfill

```
if(!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position){
    return this.substr(position || 0, searchString.length) === searchString;
  };
}
```